# Tokenizing the text without the use of libraries

Tags: python-3.8

I'm trying my best to write a function that tokenizes a text
Input: string;
Output: list (of tokens)
The tokenizer should separate the punctuation from the words, whenever the punctuation is not an
integral part of the word.
For instance:
"The current population of U.S.A. is 332,087,410 as of Friday, 01/22/2021, based on Worldometer
elaboration of the latest United Nations’ data."
should be tokenized as
"The current population of U.S.A. is 332,087,410 as of Friday , 01/22/2021 , based on Worldometer
elaboration of the latest United Nations ’ data ."

- tokenization of . (do not tokenize acronyms, abbreviations, numbers)
- tokenization of ' (expand when needed, e.g., I’m -> I am; tokenize the possessive,
  e.g., Sunday’s -> Sunday  ‘s; etc.)
- tokenization of dates (keep dates together)
- tokenization of - (keep phrases separated by - together)
- tokenization of , (do not tokenize numbers)

Been working on this for hours trying to use stuff with re and .split(), but nothing seems to be working. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try this out? This function will not handle all the possible edge cases. But this should work in most cases :

```
import re

def tokenize(text):
    tokens = text.split()
    
    i = 0
    while i < len(tokens):
        token = tokens[i]
        
        if re.match(r'\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{4}', token):
            pass
        
        elif re.match(r"\w+'s", token):
            token = re.sub(r"(\w+)'s", r"\1 's", token)
        
        elif re.match(r"\w+'\w+", token):
            token = token.replace("'", "")
        
        elif re.match(r"\w+-\w+", token):
            pass
        
        elif re.match(r"\d+(,\d+)*", token):
            pass
        
        else:
            token = re.sub(r"([^\w\s]+)", r" \1 ", token)
        
        token = re.sub(r"(\w+)\.", r"\1", token)
        token = re.sub(r"(\w+),", r"\1", token)
        token = re.sub(r"U\.S\.A\.", r"U.S.A.", token)
        
        tokens[i] = token
        i += 1
    
    return tokens
```

Comment: this outputs ['The', 'current', 'population', 'of', 'U . S . A . ', 'is', '332,087,410', 'as', 'of', 'Friday , ', '01/22/2021,', 'based', 'on', 'Worldometer', 'elaboration', 'of', 'the', 'latest', 'United', 'Nations ’ ', 'data . ']

Comment: The only issues here is "Nations'" not being "Nation" and "'", the "data ." not being "data", and "Friday ,"

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt resolve the issue, and the new output is still ['The', 'current', 'population', 'of', 'U . S . A . ', 'is', '332,087,410', 'as', 'of', 'Friday , ', '01/22/2021', 'based', 'on', 'Worldometer', 'elaboration', 'of', 'the', 'latest', 'United', 'Nations ’ ', 'data . ']

Also I didnt seem to notice at first but the U.S.A ends up having spaces in between the periods

Comment: Check the updated code.. I've updated it again.. And please keep in mind that I'm just trying my best without even running the code, I just formatted my laptop so.. xD

Comment: no worries haha, i'm also trying my best
the output is still
['The', 'current', 'population', 'of', 'U . S . A . ', 'is', '332087410', 'as', 'of', 'Friday , ', '01/22/2021', 'based', 'on', 'Worldometer', 'elaboration', 'of', 'the', 'latest', 'United', 'Nations ’ ', 'data . ']